# ConfigurationException: Expected: Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Diagnostics.ILogger. Got: Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Diagnostics.Logger

Tags: configuration

I am migrating from Sitecore 8.1 to Sitecore 9.1 and I'm getting this weird error:

```
Unexpected object type created from configuration node. 
  Expected: Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Diagnostics.ILogger. 
  Got: Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Diagnostics.Logger. 
  XML: 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current
web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error
and where it originated in the code.
```

The full stacktrace is as follows:

```
[ConfigurationException: Unexpected object type created from configuration node. Expected: Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Diagnostics.ILogger. Got: Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Diagnostics.Logger. XML: ]
 Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode) +604
 Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.ApiContainer.GetUserAccessGuard() +21
 Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.Http.Filters.DenyAnonymousUserFilterAttribute..ctor() +13
 System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateCaInstance(RuntimeType type, IRuntimeMethodInfo ctor) +0
 System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent) +2074
 System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeType type, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit) +205
 System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.InvokeAttributesOnControllerType(HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type type) +78
 System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor..ctor(HttpConfiguration configuration, String controllerName, Type controllerType) +131
 System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerSelector.InitializeControllerInfoCache() +569
 System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +708
 System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() +184
 System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerSelector.GetControllerMapping() +18
 System.Web.Http.Routing.AttributeRoutingMapper.AddRouteEntries(SubRouteCollection collector, HttpConfiguration configuration, IInlineConstraintResolver constraintResolver, IDirectRouteProvider directRouteProvider) +76
 System.Web.Http.Routing.c__DisplayClass1_1.b__1() +75
 System.Web.Http.Routing.RouteCollectionRoute.EnsureInitialized(Func`1 initializer) +66
 System.Web.Http.Routing.c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(HttpConfiguration config) +125
 Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Web.Http.ServicesConfigurator.Configure(HttpConfiguration config, RouteCollection routes) +762
 Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore.Pipelines.ServicesWebApiInitializer.Process(PipelineArgs args) +194
 (Object , Object ) +14
 Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
 Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
 Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
 Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Application_Start() +215
 Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +1184
 System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +581
 System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +168
 System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +277
 System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +369

[HttpException (0x80004005): Unexpected object type created from configuration node. Expected: Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Diagnostics.ILogger. Got: Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Diagnostics.Logger. XML: ]
 System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +532
 System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +111
 System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +714
```

The XML configuration line mentioned in the exception comes straight from the Sitecore 9.1 default config.

I inspected the **Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics** dll with DotPeek, and I could find no reason why `Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Diagnostics.Logger` couldn't implement `Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Diagnostics.ILogger`.

**Question**

Why am I getting this exception? How can I remedy to that?

Comment: What does your <experienceAnalytics><api><logger> node look like in the configuration?

Comment: It fails with the same error.If I Rebuild the entire Solution it works and I get what you would expect: `<logger type="Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Diagnostics.Logger, Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core" singleInstance="true"/>`

but then on the website I get a weird error about an HTML Helper missing when instead it's there: `'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' does not contain a definition...`.

If I Build again - rather than Rebuild - I get the same error as before.

Comment: Do you have any old 8.1 references in your project and hence DLLs hanging around in the bin folder?

Comment: Could be an explanation. I will try removing all the references and only add 9.1 ones. I also have some libraries whose version exceed that of the vanilla 9.1 - HtmlAgilityPack, System.Web.Http.WebHost, Newtonsoft.Json, etc.

Do you think that having _newer_ versions could be an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a reference to the old Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.dll file, version 1.1.0.5295.

In version 9.1 this is split in several different files, but keeping a reference to the old one was causing the above mentioned issue.